# how to save has many through association in controller in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, has-and-belongs-to-many, mass-assignment

i have a `Projects` model and `User` model. i want to establish `has many through association` between these models. now my requirement is i want to  list all the users in the `multiselect` drop down, in `projects/new` form, by this i want to assign all users belongs to this project while creating the project. similarly while creating a new user in `users/new` form, i want to list all the `projects` in  `multiselect` dropdown.  here what should be controller logic in `Projects_controller/create` action and similarly what should be the logic in  `Users_controller/create` action so that i can save these has many associations in controller?

Answer (score 0):

use something like

```
@user = User.create(...)
@projects = params[:projects].map{|k,v| Project.find(k)}
@user.projects << @projects
```